# AngularJS / S3 - Convert arrayBuffer into blob "failed to load PDF document"

Tags: angularjs, pdf, amazon-s3

I've been looking for hours trying to find the solution to this.

I am hitting an endpoint in my node and express app and am getting back an arraybuffer, but when I try to view the blob I get the error "Failed to load PDF document"

Here is my angular service

```
app.service('aws', function($http, $q) {

  this.getObject = function(file_name){
    return $q.when($http.get(api + 'aws/getObject?file_name=' + file_name, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}))
  }

})
```

and then me envoking it

```
aws.getObject(filename).then(function(response){
    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    $scope.document = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL)
})
```

I've even tried just using the response

```
aws.getObject(filename).then(function(response){
    var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    $scope.document = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL)
})
```

And then display it here

```
<object data="{{document}}" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%; height:400px" />
```

But no matter what I've tried it still returns "Failed to load PDF document"

Comment: provide more details about the error and try to console response.data and response and check which one will print data correctly.